# Pivot table like mysql structure

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help with a mySQL statement. 
I currently have the following data which captures every change in delivery dates of different orders (with order number):

```
Order number    Delivery date

VO15010228-1    2015-06-11
VO15010228-1    2015-05-10
VO15010969-1    2015-06-25 
VO15010969-1    2015-05-25
```

I need to display this into a table like this:

```
Order number    Current del. date     Previous del. date
VO15010228-1    2015-06-11            2015-05-10
VO15010969-1    2015-06-25            2015-05-25
```

I tried group_concat in my SQL statement, but I can't work with multiple dates into one single value. Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, MAX(DeliveryDate) AS Current, MIN(DeliveryDate) AS Previous
FROM mytable
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

It will work for a simple scenario like the one of your sample data.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19e34/1)